# UI Router conflicting when using similar URL pattern

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have the following 2 states defined in my app.config:

```
state('product-details', {
    url: '/products/:productId',
    templateUrl: '/pages/product-details/product-details.tmpl.html',
    controller: 'ProductDetailsController'
})
```

and

```
state('product-register', {
    url: '/products/register',
    templateUrl: '/pages/product-register/product-register.tmpl.html',
    controller: 'ProductRegisterController'
})
```

The problem I am facing is since both their URL patterns are similar, when I try to navigate to `product-register` state, the 'register' is interpreted by angularui-router as a `productId` and redirects me to `product-details` state instead.

After going through some similar questions on SO, I thought I would filter these URLs using regexes as explained [here](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/URL-Routing#regex-parameters). But when I tried this, although the regex was matching properly in isolation, the state refused to change.

Then again after doing a bit of research I decided to merge the two states like this:

```
state('product-details', {
     url: '/products/:param',
    templateUrl: ['$stateParams', function($stateParams) {
        if($stateParams.param === 'register') {
            return '/pages/product-register/product-register.tmpl.html';
        } else {
            return '/pages/product-details/product-details.tmpl.html';
        }
    }],
    controller: ['$stateParams', function($stateParams) {
        if($stateParams.param === 'register') {
            return 'ProductRegisterController';
        } else {
            return 'ProductDetailsController';
        }
    }]
})
```

This also does not seem to work as expected. What am I missing? Isn't this a very normal thing you would have to do?

Comment: Can't you just describe your route as `url: '/products/detail/:productId'`?

Comment: I could, but that's not my point :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to move 'product-register' state before 'product-details' state.

Actually you need to differentiate your state URL pattern or else angular will fire the first match it will find.

Comment: Thanks! Funny that switching the order didn't pass the problem to the other state. Now both just work

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to specify types for your parameters to match only certain states.

In your case you could use:

```
url: '/products/{productId:int}'
```

There are lots of other examples on the ui router page:
https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/URL-Routing

Comment: This seems feasible, however my ids are Strings

Comment: Is there any defined pattern for your ids that you could use a regex for? Otherwise it might be difficult without differentiating urls more :/

Comment: You need to have uniq identifiers for states, one way, if you have some pattern could be using regular expressions (Ui.Router has a basic support on it)...

Howewer, the best solution is having unique identifiers...

Comment: What if we can´t control that? Im my case I have no way of knowing if "/products" is a category or a cms page :/